# Average temperature in different cities

Tags: arrays

Suppose that temperature measurements were made on 7 days of 2009 in each of 5 cities .write a program that will read the city name followed by the  temperature measurements of that city.The city name and measurements should be stored in two array .The program should find out the average temperature of each city.Also you should find the average temperature of each day?
thank you

Comment: If this is homework, tag it as such.

Comment: Pseudo code should be good enough. It is a homework assignment after all.

Comment: Show us how you have tried to answer the question and how far you've gotten with it. We SOers like to help people to understand, not just to get an answer. Also, what language?(or is it just psuedo code?)

Comment: What have you tried so far, and why didn't it work? People should not answer your homework questions for you without that information, and even then they should only give you ideas on how to do it.

Comment: Instead of us doing your homework for you, you might want to show us what you have, and ask questions about where you're stuck.  Or, you know, pay someone to do your homework, and please don't take any career in technology or management.

Comment: Too often though, someone will hand the answer on a plate anyways. Anything for some rep, or so it seems.

Comment: @pjp I would assume either `2 arrays` or a `2 dimensional array`

Comment: What have you done on your problem so far?  Have you broken out elements of it?  Have you figured out how to do the i/o?  What are the problems that you're having?

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to know how to start without knowing the language.  But if you're struggling with how to store this data, here's an idea in C++:

```
class CityData
{
  string City;
  float Temperatures[]; // array of temperatures
}

void main()
{
  CityData MyCityData[5]; // array of CityData
  MyCityData[0] = new CityData();
  MyCityData[0].City = "Dallas";
  MyCityData[0].Temperatures = { 50, 60, 63, 43, 75, 25, 64 };
  // and so on
}
```

Hopefully you can use this to accomplish the rest.

Comment: It is a good idea. However, arrays and loops are typically tought way before classes.

Comment: @Steve: See my comment to Nick above. You're only hurting yourself (and other developers) by providing actual code instead of concepts or at best pseudo-code. (Particularly for posters who can't even identify the language for which they need help.)

Comment: @Ken - That's why I didn't solve the problem -- I only provided a starting point.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need an array of numbers (not hard) and an array of strings (easy) or an array of characters (not hard).

You then get two index variables.  The first indexes for the city (c) and the second indexes for the temperature (t).

You then setup a loop for the city.  Set the index (c) to your language's array starting point (in most languages this is 0).

Read the city name and store it in the name array indexed to 0.

Next you want to setup a loop for the temperature.  Again, start (t) at the beginning index.

Now the fun begins.  You need to read the temperature and store it in the array at the position [t + c* MaxTemps].  (MaxTemps should be 7 in your case).

Read in all the temps increasing the index as you go.

Then increase the city index and read in the next city name.  If you are using an array of strings, just put the next city name in the second position.  If instead you are using an array of characters, you will need to have an array that is [maxChars * maxCities] long.  You will then need to put the second name in the [c * maxChars] spot.

Now you should reset the temperature index and read in the temperatures for the next city.

Continue looping until all data has been read.

Output is similar to input.  To get the average of the city read the data from [t + c * MaxTemps] ... [MaxTemps -1 +  c*MaxTemps].

To get the average of each day, read the data from [t + c*maxTemps] ...[t + (maxCities -1) * MaxTemps]

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.*;
class CityData
{
public static void main(Strang args[])
int[][]b=new int[8][6]
string[][]a=new string[2][2]

Scanner cp=new scanner(System.in)


System.out.println("Enter your first data");
for(i=0;i<=1;i++)
a[i][j]=cp.next[];

System.out.println("Enter your seconed data");
for(i=0;i<=1;i++){
for(j=0;j<=1;j++)}

a[i][j]=cp.nextint();
for(i=0;i<=1;i++){
for(j=0;j<=1;j++)}
}}
```

This is my answer, but it is without the average because I don't know how can I write it.